# Making sense out of VS2010 Coded UI Debug Trace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm working with VS 2010 CUIT projects and have run into some issues that I'm having a hard time understanding.  Namely 2 things are causing me troubles:

1. In the Debug Trace I get messages of the type: "PERF WARNING: FindAllDescendents took XXXX ms.  Expected it to take maximum 500 ms".  I understand what the warning means, but I can't always (easily) determine which query is causing the issue.  Is there a way to add more information to the debug trace that would include the information I'm looking for?
2. I also see messages like this one: "PERF WARNING: CacheQueryId: took XXX ms. Expected it to take maximum 100 ms."  I can't figure out what the warning really means or if there's anything that can be done to "fix" it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found across this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2009/11/29/how-to-enable-tracing-for-ui-test-components.aspx) that explains how to increase the level of details in debug trace.  I added the following registry keys:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\EnterpriseTools\QualityTools\Diagnostics]
>
> "EnableTracing"=dword:00000001
>
> "TraceLevel"=dword:00000004

and can now see the information about which control exactly is taking a long time to find.  Just a warning though - there's a lot of information in the trace now so it's much harder to sift through it.

Still looking for an answer to my section question, or in general a list of warnings in the debug trace and what they mean.